I had/have saved up for months to afford it
Suppose I'm telling my friend about what's happened to me lately, and, among other things, I say to him:
1. Yesterday, I bought a new laptop. I had saved up for months to afford it. My old laptop had started to malfunction, so it was time for an upgrade. I decided to buy the latest model from my favorite brand. When I arrived at the store, I realized that I had left my wallet at home. I felt so embarrassed!
As I see it, the past perfect "had saved" means that the saving up comes before the buying. The past perfect "had started" emphasizes the fact that the old laptop started to malfunction before I bought the new one. Therefore, using the past perfect tense for the bolded verbs appears logical. Now I wonder if this version is possible:
2. Yesterday, I bought a new laptop. I have saved up for months to afford it. My old laptop started to malfunction, so it was time for an upgrade. I decided to buy the latest model from my favorite brand. When I arrived at the store, I realized that I had left my wallet at home. I felt so embarrassed!
In my view, the present perfect "has saved" is justified because I bought the laptop just yesterday, thus making the purchase very recent and a part of my present. The justification for the simple past "started" is that it's clear from the context that the old laptop started to malfunction before I bought the new one, so there's no need to use the past perfect "had started" to make that clear to the listener.
Do you agree with my reasoning, and do you think that either version can be used in this case? Thank you.

I would disregard the dv's by one person here. It is not the grammar, it is the logical sequence of events that counts here.

People might say it as in your second version, but it’s not standard grammar. The saving up that is relevant is that which created the conditions (of sufficiency of resources) that were already achieved at the time under discussion, and the time under discussion is yesterday, which is not in the present.  You couldn’t, for instance, say, *”Yesterday I have enough money to buy a new laptop.”
Unless the saving continues. In other words, if the reason for saving weren’t just to be able to buy the laptop, but further purchases still lay ahead, and you were going to continue to save, then the present perfect would be appropriate. But that’s not the situation you describe.

What about saved without had as it is obvious that the saving was before the buying of a new computer

Yes, @YvesLefol, the simple past, I saved up for months…, would be fine. Indeed, at least one frequent contributor here, FumbleFingers, encourages learners not to even bother trying to use the perfect forms until they’ve become pretty highly proficient in English.

(@fumblefingers, are you listening?)

I am! And I disagree with the pedantic "not considered correct grammar", as you probably expected! In the OP's specific example #2, I have no objection to Present Perfect being used by even the most careful speaker, to add "immediacy" to the fact that the saving up extends from way in the past, to only just yesterday. It's a context-specific way of being "emphatic" (to non-pedants! :)

@FumbleFingers Call it what you will. It is not logical at all. "I saw a cat yesterday. I haven't seen a cat recently".  No way. It's not about grammar per se, it's about the logic of the past tenses. Grammar is one thing; logical time sequences another, signaled by past tenses.

Just out of interest, would you still say the same if it had started This morning I bought a new laptop... ??? How long ago does the purchase have to be before you accept Present rather than Past Perfect for the preceding process of saving? What if the speaker is just leaving the shop? I just bought a new laptop...

@FumbleFingers What present? You didn't finish your example so I can not answer question.

Yes, @FumbleFingers, I would still say the same because (1) the form I bought situates the buying in the past, and (2) the saving was performed during some period that had ended before the buying took place.

bought/saved up OR bought/had saved up but NOT: bought [yesterday]/have saved up. Not due to grammar per se, but rather due to the logic of the activities.

Btw @FumbleFingers (and in case the down vote was yours), would you have been happy if I had said instead, “but it’s not standard grammar”? I’m going to make that change anyway so the answer doesn’t come off as prescriptive.

Absolutely! I might interpret "non-standard" different to you (I might think it's just "less common", you might think it's "less correct").

@FumbleFingers, I don’t think I’m all that prescriptive, though my kids might beg to differ…

I just think we need to be careful about "correct / incorrect" in the context of learners. There are just so many contexts where in practice it really doesn't matter which of two or more alternatives you use, but questions like this often virtually force many native speakers to endorse just one version. Even though if they were in casual conversation with another native speaker, they wouldn't think anything of it if they heard one of the alternatives. And imho, that's the level most learners should aspire to reach (not the level that gets marks from pedantic examiners).

It's the same as when a learner asks about the difference between two or more words. People feel compelled to find the tiniest nuance of difference (spurious or not), when so often it's not that important.

I respect your position, @FumbleFingers. It reminds me, though, of the sensation I felt when my prof for 3rd-semester Russian announced, “We’ve actually been lying to you about verbs from the start. There’s this thing in Russian called aspect, and it’s so hairy for English speakers to learn that if we’d introduced it right out of the gate, you probably all would have dropped RUS 101.” I understood their pedagogical choice, but I also resented having been taught “fake” Russian grammar. Maybe that experience was influential in my preference to deal with the English perfect ab initio.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

1) is fine,
Yesterday, I bought a new laptop. I had saved up for months to afford it.
2) is not. You don't follow a simple past with a present perfect in those two related things. Use the simple past for both.
Changed:  Yesterday, I bought a new laptop. I saved up for it.
But one can do this:
I haven't seen them recently but yesterday I spoke to them on the phone.

@PaulTanenbaum What are you objecting to? I have three, perfectly grammatical examples there and my answer is very clear.

@PaulTanenbaum ok, I changed it.

I don't agree that OP's #2 is incorrect. As the OP says, the purchase [was] very recent and a part of [his] "present". That works for me.


Yesterday, I bought a new laptop. I have saved up for months to afford it [at the time of speaking now]. My old laptop started to malfunction.  is not great.


It is not grammatically incorrect. It is contextually incorrect.
